# Colima unable to recognise service name in connection string ORA - 12514

Tags: docker, apple-m1, colima

I am using Apple M1 Pro chip laptop.
Need to have oracle DB for which docker desktop is not working(known issue with M1 chip)
Workaround that I found was to use colima (it worked for my colleagues with M1 chip)

However, I am facing issue with colima as well.

```
sam@sam-mac ~ % colima status
INFO[0000] colima is running               
INFO[0000] arch: x86_64                 
INFO[0000] runtime: docker                
INFO[0000] mountType: sshfs               
INFO[0000] socket: unix:///Users/sam/.colima/default/docker.sock

sam@sam-mac ~ % docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                                        COMMAND         CREATED       STATUS     PORTS                    NAMES
f9d24cdb87f4  ImageName  "/sbin/simple_init.py"  About an hour ago  Up 21 minutes  0.0.0.0:1521->1521/tcp, :::1521->1521/tcp  oracle_database
```

When I try to connect via sql developer ,I get the following error

```
Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
```

Same steps are working good for others with M1 chip. Kindly suggest..Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

From inside the docker container :

```
ps -ef 

bash-4.2# ps -ef
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 11:45 ?        00:00:00 /bin/python2.7 /sbin/simple_init.py
root         7     1  0 11:45 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/runsvdir -P /etc/service CMD_L_LOG: .....................................................................
root         8     7  0 11:45 ?        00:00:00 runsv oracle-database
root         9     7  0 11:45 ?        00:00:00 runsv oracle-listener
root        10     9  0 11:45 ?        00:00:00 su oracle -c /usr/local/bin/oracle-listener
root        11     8  0 11:45 ?        00:00:00 su oracle -c /usr/local/bin/oracle-database
oracle      12    11  0 11:45 ?        00:00:02 /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/oracle-database
oracle      29    10  0 11:45 ?        00:00:01 /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/oracle-listener
oracle      41     1  0 11:45 ?        00:00:05 /u01/app/oracle/product/database/12.1.0.2.190416_2/bin/tnslsnr LISTENER -inherit
oracle     107     1  0 11:46 ?        00:00:02 ora_pmon_orcl
oracle     109     1  0 11:46 ?        00:00:04 ora_psp0_orcl
oracle     113     1  0 11:46 ?        00:00:09 ora_vktm_orcl
oracle     117     1  0 11:46 ?        00:00:01 ora_gen0_orcl
oracle     119     1  0 11:46 ?        00:00:01 ora_mman_orcl
oracle     123     1  0 11:46 ?        00:00:03 ora_diag_orcl
oracle     125     1  0 11:46 ?        00:00:05 ora_dbrm_orcl
oracle     127     1  0 11:46 ?        00:00:00 ora_vkrm_orcl
oracle     129     1  0 11:46 ?        00:00:07 ora_dia0_orcl
oracle     131     1  0 11:46 ?        00:00:14 ora_dbw0_orcl
oracle     133     1  0 11:46 ?        00:00:02 ora_lgwr_orcl
oracle     135     1  0 11:46 ?        00:00:06 ora_ckpt_orcl
oracle     137     1  0 11:46 ?        00:00:01 ora_lg00_orcl
oracle     139     1  0 11:46 ?        00:00:01 ora_smon_orcl
oracle     141     1  0 11:46 ?        00:00:00 ora_lg01_orcl
oracle     143     1  0 11:46 ?        00:00:00 ora_reco_orcl
oracle     145     1  0 11:46 ?        00:00:01 ora_lreg_orcl
oracle     147     1  0 11:46 ?        00:00:01 ora_pxmn_orcl
oracle     149     1  1 11:46 ?        00:00:28 ora_mmon_orcl
oracle     151     1  0 11:46 ?        00:00:12 ora_mmnl_orcl
oracle     153     1  0 11:46 ?        00:00:00 ora_d000_orcl
oracle     155     1  0 11:46 ?        00:00:00 ora_s000_orcl
oracle     173     1  0 11:46 ?        00:00:00 ora_tmon_orcl
oracle     175     1  0 11:46 ?        00:00:01 ora_tt00_orcl
oracle     177     1  0 11:46 ?        00:00:01 ora_smco_orcl
oracle     181     1  0 11:46 ?        00:00:00 ora_w001_orcl
oracle     185     1  0 11:46 ?        00:00:00 ora_aqpc_orcl
oracle     191     1  0 11:46 ?        00:00:07 ora_p000_orcl
oracle     193     1  0 11:46 ?        00:00:02 ora_p001_orcl
oracle     195     1  0 11:46 ?        00:00:02 ora_p002_orcl
oracle     197     1  0 11:46 ?        00:00:01 ora_p003_orcl
oracle     199     1  0 11:46 ?        00:00:00 ora_p004_orcl
oracle     201     1  0 11:46 ?        00:00:00 ora_p005_orcl
oracle     203     1  0 11:46 ?        00:00:00 ora_p006_orcl
oracle     205     1  0 11:46 ?        00:00:00 ora_p007_orcl
oracle     209     1  1 11:46 ?        00:00:14 ora_cjq0_orcl
oracle     215     1  0 11:46 ?        00:00:00 ora_qm02_orcl
oracle     221     1  0 11:46 ?        00:00:00 ora_q003_orcl
oracle     223     1  0 11:46 ?        00:00:00 ora_q004_orcl
oracle     972     1  0 11:53 ?        00:00:00 ora_w002_orcl
oracle    1667     1  0 12:01 ?        00:00:00 ora_w003_orcl
oracle    1676     1  0 12:01 ?        00:00:00 ora_w004_orcl
oracle    1972     1  0 12:05 ?        00:00:00 ora_p008_orcl
oracle    1974     1  0 12:05 ?        00:00:00 ora_p009_orcl
oracle    1999     1  0 12:05 ?        00:00:00 ora_p00a_orcl
oracle    2001     1  0 12:05 ?        00:00:00 ora_p00b_orcl
oracle    2005     1  1 12:05 ?        00:00:05 ora_q001_orcl
```

Comment: What connection string are you using in SQL Developer? Also, what's the output of ```lsnrctl status``` inside your Docker container?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt lsnrctl status is giving command Not found.
I tried orcl as service name.

Comment: Try /u01/app/oracle/product/database/12.1.0.2.190416_2/bin/lsnrctl . And please provide the connection string you're using in SQL Developer, as well.